# PHPUnit not showing diff on assertEquals failure

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit 3.7.10 via CakePHP v2.3 and I run the following:

```
$this->assertEquals(array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('a', 'c', 'd'));
```

And all I get is:

`Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.`

Why do I not get the diff below as outlined here? http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertEquals.example5

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     0 => 'a'
-    1 => 'b'
-    2 => 'c'
+    1 => 'c'
+    2 => 'd'
 )
```

What am I missing?

**Update**. Test file called via test.php?case=Cache/Engine/PhpUnit&debug=1

```
<?php

class PhpUnitTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public function testDiff() {
        $this->assertEquals(array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('a', 'c', 'd'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really that simple example that fails or have you simplified it for SO?

Comment: please post your entire test so we can determine better what is happening.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know the exact command you're running (i.e. any flags, piping stdout/err)

Comment: I've added a sample test case. Yes its that simple.

Comment: I've created http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/3503-23-suppresses-phpunit-diff-output will update this q when it gets figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a regression bug in CakePHP 2.3.  Fixed in https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/659715664d648d9a599002b5a7c3b55505efdcde

For ref here was the ticked I opened:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3503-23-suppresses-phpunit-diff-output

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
<?php
class SoTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testIt()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('a', 'c', 'd'));
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
$  phpunit SoTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) SoTest::testIt
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     0 => 'a'
-    1 => 'b'
-    2 => 'c'
+    1 => 'c'
+    2 => 'd'
 )

/home/cweiske/SoTest.php:6

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: per my post, im running this in CakePHP 2.3. Think its a problem with the framework suppressing output

Answer (score 0):

You are running the unit tests on the browser. You will see the expected result when you run it on the CLI with `--debug` modifier. You can also try adding `&debug=1` at the end of the url when using the web browser to run the tests but that has not worked many times for me.

Comment: Yes I am indeed running web version of the test cases. I always enable debug. still no output. Glad to see its not just me.  I'm guessing its a bug with how cake is suppressing output. Also, I cant get the 2.3 console to recognize my test cases. 'app$ ./Console/cake test' is giving me 'No test cases available'

Comment: In order to run test case from command line, you have to specify the path of model,controller or anything else you are trying to test. `Console/cake test Model/Model1`